# is there any possible negative repercussions from not closing down mysql connections

Tags: php, mysql, database

so suppose I connect to mysql with my php script as usual, but then suppose I never actually call any code that would close that connection and just let it be until the page is served to the user

Is there any reason why I shouldn't be doing this? What negative consequences may arise (if any) if I do this?

Comment: I think server has a timeout value and will close the connection after this time has passed without any activity

Comment: @KristerAndersson - That's possible, but they're not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the mysql extension you are using **not** closing the connection is actually beneficial as this will allow the use of persistent connections. That means the connection is only opened the first time the script runs, and every subsequent run the already-open mysql connection is used, reconnecting as needed. This is a bit faster and less resource intensive then opening and closing the connection on every single request. If you are using `mysqli` then persistent connections should be possible and are preferable.

Even if your mysql extension doesn't support persistent connections, or isn't configured to use them, that just means the connection will close when the script exits, which is no different than closing it yourself, which means closing it manually gains you nothing.

Conclusion: closing the connection yourself probably gains you nothing and might actually hurt performance.

**edit**: See `mysql.allow_persistent` and `mysqli.allow_persistent` to configure whether or not persistent connections are used for mysql, depending on which mysql extension you are using.

Comment: I'm wondering, is this the same thing as [connection pooling in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool)?

Comment: @Jared Farrish -- Not exactly. Connection pools work a bit different, so theoretically a connection pool of just 5 connections could service 20 java processes... if a connection isn't available in the pool the process will just have to block (wait) for a connection to come available. Persistent connections in PHP are similar, but are **strictly** one-per-process, so if there are 20 PHP processes, there has to be 20 persistent connections, and they are never shared. See http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Being a PHP-based "scripter", we just recently had a problem with an Atlassian product (JIRA using the internal Crowd AD connector) where a sync against ~4000 groups and ~24000 users was taking ~4 hours to finish using SSL (5 minutes otherwise). However, once we passed a pooled connection flag to the JVM, the SSL sync time dropped to ~4.5 minutes. This was a tangent, I know, but I was wondering if it was similar.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout out the php option

```
; http://php.net/mysql.allow-persistent
mysql.allow_persistent = On
```

This should help, if you can set this.

Comment: This configuration option appears to be for MS SQL, not MySQL.

Comment: Grr... you edited your answer but it won't let me take away the down vote. Bug?

Answer (score 1):

Like any unoptimized code, failing to close() or kill() the socket will usually not become evident until the site/application is under heavy demand, i.e., lots of page requests are being sent to the server.  By not killing+closing and freeing up the socket after the request has been serviced, the socket sits in a a 'wait' state for a short period of time, adding to the load of any new socket connections occurring when new page loads and connection attempts are made.  Given very high traffic conditions, these sockets will continue to accumulate in process memory, possibly (based on your max connections and max_user_connections params) leading to the ubiquitous "Max connections reached...." message.

Garbage collection that occurs after the script has completed will not necessarily recycle the socket endpoint.  As far as I know, only calling mysqli_kill() after mysqli_close() will actually kill the socket.

As for persistent connections, you don't mention which mysql api you're using or the server and how php is loaded into the server and network topology.  Persistent connections allow you to avoid the overhead of opening a connection to mysql.  If mysql runs on the same box as the web server, persistent connections probably won't buy much scalability.  If php runs in a cgi process, persistent connections will not work because the php process only exists during the lifetime of the request. Don't confuse persistent connections with JDBC connection pooling, they're not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP has garbage collection, when the script finishes on the server, the connection is closed. Unless you specified it as a persistent connection.

From the php reference:

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution.

You can read more at the mysql_close reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php).